# How to insert into Postgres table with the PG gem

Tags: ruby, postgresql, pg

I created three DB schemas with Postgres. The tables are definitely there, I used the shell with `\dt` to see them.

My SqlRunner is failing when trying to make an INSERT with my seeds.rb file. The terminal returns a PG::SyntaxError at or near "11.18". The previous line is also a float, so I don't know what's wrong.

The model looks like:

```
require('pg')
require('../project_giclee_db/sql_runner')


class Material

  attr_reader :id, :product_name, :guk_name, :roll_width_in,  :roll_length_metres, :list_price, :cost_per_sqm,
    :cost_per_sqm_with_ink, :factor_n, :sell_per_sqm, :rounded_sale_price


  def initialize( options )
    @id = options['id'].to_i
    @product_name = options['product_name']
    @guk_name = options['guk_name']
    @roll_width_in = options['roll_width_in'].to_i
    @roll_length_metres = options['roll_length_metres'].to_i
    @list_price = options['list_price'].to_f
    @cost_per_sqm = options['cost_per_sqm'].to_f
    @cost_per_sqm_with_ink = options['cost_per_sqm_with_ink'].to_f
    @factor_n = options['factor_n'].to_f
    @sell_per_sqm = options['sell_per_sqm'].to_f
    @rounded_sale_price = options['rounded_sale_price'].to_i

  end


  def save
    sql = "INSERT INTO materials (product_name, guk_name, roll_width_in, roll_length_metres,
    list_price, cost_per_sqm, cost_per_sqm_with_ink, factor_n, sell_per_sqm, rounded_sale_price)
    VALUES (#{@product_name}, #{@guk_name}, #{@roll_width_in}, #{@roll_length_metres}, #{@list_price}
    #{@cost_per_sqm}, #{@cost_per_sqm_with_ink}, #{@factor_n}, #{@sell_per_sqm}, #{@rounded_sale_price}
    ) RETURNING *"

    data = SqlRunner.run(sql).first
    @id = data['id']
  end


  def self.delete_all
    sql = "DELETE FROM materials"
    SqlRunner.run(sql)
  end

end
```

Runner looks like:

```
require('pg')

class SqlRunner

  def self.run(sql)
    begin
   db = PG.connect( {dbname: 'giclee_db', host: 'localhost'} )
     result = db.exec(sql)
    ensure
    db.close
  end
   return result
 end

end
```

Seed data looks like:

```
require('../models/materials')
require('pry-byebug')

Material.delete_all

 @material1 = Material.new( { 'product_name' => 'giclee_canvas',   'guk_name' => 'canvas',
'roll_width_in' => 44, 'roll_length_metres' => 12, 'list_price' => 150.00,
'cost_per_sqm' => 11.18, 'cost_per_sqm_with_ink' => 14.18, 'factor_n' => 11.00,
'sell_per_sqm' => 156.03, 'rounded_sale_price' => 156
} )


@material1.save
```

Comment: I'd highly recommend using [Sequel](http://sequel.jeremyevans.net) when talking to databases if you are not using Rails. It's a very good ORM that will make it much easier to generate queries or statements without needing to worry about the syntax. Pg forces you to write SQL specific to PostgreSQL. Sequel lets you use Ruby to generate the SQL and is DBM agnostic, [supporting many different DBMs](http://sequel.jeremyevans.net/rdoc-adapters/index.html), and you only change your DSN to have it automatically generate equivalent queries for a different database type.

Comment: In Ruby it's idiomatic to not use parenthesis around the `require` parameter. Also `@material1` shows you don't understand variables and their scope with Ruby. I'd recommend getting familiar with class, instance and local variables, and constants.

Comment: Alright! Had a look, seems promising. I am ready to jump train with pg, I only want to model a database. I will use rails later to build the API. Sequel looks more user friendly. Thanks @The Tin Man

Comment: I admit that I am relatively new to this, but none of the things you mention will disrupt the SqlRunner.

Comment: What you are referring to is the style, I was taught to put parenthesis there, so I do; out of habit.

Comment: While you might have been taught to, that wasn't the recommended standard, making your code non-idiomatic for the language. It's a good idea to read/adopt the Ruby style-guides and enable Rubocop in your editor. Failing to do so will definitely raise questions in code reviews.

Comment: Pg is great as a driver to talk to PostgreSQL, but writing SQL by hand isn't a good use of time when good ORMs are available. Sequel is very well maintained and the author uses Postgres for his database so Sequel supports it very well.

Comment: Fair play. I don't want to freak any Rubyists out with my laid-back use of the language. As I said I am a new comer and only post on stackoverflow when I really need to. Rubocop? Sounds interesting. I need a Rubocop. I don't want bad reviews so a Rubocop I will acquire. Thanks for letting me know about sequel, I used the pg method at the school, but it is tedious and laborsome. They wanted to teach us the long and hard way, I suppose.

Comment: They wanted to teach you the low-level way so you learned SQL, which is fine but in production environments we don't like doing that. It wastes time and makes it harder to move from local development to test and production, especially when the DBM changes. Occasionally we still have to write native code but we can bottle-neck that to reduce the impact.

Answer (score 1):

You should have quotes around your strings:

```
def save
 sql = "INSERT INTO materials (product_name, guk_name, roll_width_in, roll_length_metres,
list_price, cost_per_sqm, cost_per_sqm_with_ink, factor_n, sell_per_sqm, rounded_sale_price)
VALUES ('#{@product_name}', '#{@guk_name}', #{@roll_width_in}, #{@roll_length_metres}, #{@list_price}
#{@cost_per_sqm}, #{@cost_per_sqm_with_ink}, #{@factor_n}, #{@sell_per_sqm}, #{@rounded_sale_price}
) RETURNING *"

  data = SqlRunner.run(sql).first
  @id = data['id']
end
```

Comment: good shout @eiko, but I get the same error. Made the change, progress is progress.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is a missing comma at the end the line in the SQL:

```
VALUES ('#{@product_name}', '#{@guk_name}', #{@roll_width_in}, #{@roll_length_metres}, #{@list_price}
```

Comment: Line breaks in variable sql also is bad.
Try without Line breaks.
 
sql = "INSERT INTO materials (product_name, guk_name, roll_width_in, roll_length_metres, list_price, cost_per_sqm, cost_per_sqm_with_ink, factor_n, sell_per_sqm, rounded_sale_price) VALUES ('#{@product_name}', '#{@guk_name}', #{@roll_width_in}, #{@roll_length_metres}, #{@list_price}, #{@cost_per_sqm}, #{@cost_per_sqm_with_ink}, #{@factor_n}, #{@sell_per_sqm}, #{@rounded_sale_price} ) RETURNING *"

Comment: Why is it bad @rafael.cote?

Comment: Anyway I am in the hot seat, the pry lid is open and I have a returned object hash. Thanks

Comment: @godhar I thought the "\n" would give an error when executed, but it worked for me.

Comment: yeah I basically only had it this way so I could see it in the editor. Cheers @rafael.cote

Comment: Be more specific. _WHERE_ is the comma missing? Embedded line breaks in SQL are fine. Try it in the command-line some time.

Comment: @theTinMan add line with problem. I am started at stackoverflow.